# Populando um campo através da seleção de um dropdowlist através de popup

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, popup

Estou precisando abrir um pop-up atráves do evento de seleção de um `dropdownlist` em uma aplicação **.net** e desta forma popularei o campo da primeira tela com a seleção da opção exibida pelo *popup*. Confesso que sou meio leigo com o javascript e pelo que verifiquei pode ser utilizado o `Page.ClientScript`, porém gostaria de uma orientação como trabalhar com este método ou outro que sane minha necessidade.

Necessito de uma forma para capturar a seleção de um `dropdownlist` para abrir um popup.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A maneira mais simples é usando jQuery](http://www.codemag.com/article/1411051). O jQuery [pode ser obtido aqui](http://jquery.com/download/).

Para abrir um pop-up, você pode interceptar o evento de mudança do pop-up e chamar a janela.

```
<script>
    $('#meupopup').change(function(e) {
           window.open("http://minhapagina.aspx",null,
"height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
        });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#meupopup').trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```